# Prove $\leq^∗$ is a well-order

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The binary relation $\leq^∗$ between integer pairs is defined by the following rule: for $v,w∈ℤ$, $v\leq^∗w$ if and only if one of the following conditions is satisfied:

- $|v|<|w|$, or
- $|v|=|w|$ and $v<0$, or
- $v=w$.

I want to prove $\leq^∗$ is a well order by verifying the following properties: antisymmetry, reflexivity, transitivity and comparability, and by showing that $\leq^∗$ is a well-order.

I have already proved the properties. How can I show that it is a well-order?

Comment: I could have sworn that this question was posted an hour or so ago, was reformatted with $\LaTeX$, and had three comments.

Answer (score 0):

Take the closest to zero element. If there are two — take the negative one. It'll be the least, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

By "showing that $\leq^*$ is a well-order" I assume you mean you need to verify the property that every set $S\ne\emptyset$ has a least element. Given a set $S\ne\emptyset$, you can consider the set $T=\{|s|\,|\,s\in S\}\subset\mathbf{N}$. You know that $T$ has a least element under the usual ordering of $\mathbf{N}$, since $\mathbf{N}$ is well-ordered. The least element of $S$ must be one of the preimages of this element (why?) (which preimage?).